# C++ background update

Tags: c++, auto-update

It's way to call update function on background?
I need update collection every 5 seconds.

In C# I create timer set start stop and delegate and it work.

Exist any way do it in C++?

Comment: It depends upon the operating system, or at least the library framework you want to use (e.g. [Qt](http://qt.digia.com/)...), and also of the C++ standard version. Only the latest [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) standard knows about time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On our embedded system, we create a separate task that runs in the background. 
Another method is to do most of the work through interrupts and the non-interrupt code would be running in the background.

I guess this is platform dependent, which platform are you using?

Comment: Must run on Linux and Windows.

Comment: No can do.  They each have different methods for executing functions in the background.  You will need to make separate executables.

Comment: Should be no problem. Linux and Windows have [C++11 compilers](http://isocpp.org/get-started), which allow you to use, for instance, [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async). See also: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c11s-async-template/240001196

Answer (score 2):

C++11:

```
#include <thread>

void update() {
    for (;;) {
        do_update();
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread thr(update);
    thr.detach();
    // do whatever the program needs to do
    return 0;
}
```